# Website contact form made using PHPMAILER not sending messages through

Tags: html, jquery, phpmailer, contact-form

I'm trying to get my clients website contact form to function with PHPMailer. I made use of a html template that I purchased, and edited the phpmailer code to correspond with the html template.

When I test the code separately (without the html template) through xampp it works perfectly and sends emails instantly. Even when I debug the smtp there is no errors at all. However when I connect it to the website, fill the form, and click the submit button, no action occurs. I'm therefore not sure where or what went wrong and I'm pleading with anyone to help me diagnose the issue.

Here is a code snippet of the index.html (website snippet):

```html
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 p-0">
                                <form method="POST" action="php/send.php" id="nexgen-simple-form" class="nexgen-simple-form">

                                    <div class="row form-group-margin">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control field-name" placeholder="Name" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control field-email" placeholder="Email" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control field-phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <textarea name="message" class="form-control field-message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-12 m-0 p-2 input-group">
                                            <span class="form-alert"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 input-group m-0 p-2">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn primary-button">SEND</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
```

Here is the send.php file (PHPmailer):

```html
<?php

$name = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //new variable called name, checks data posted to the page with the variable name
$phone = filter_var($_POST["phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sanitize string: secures the data, makes sure info processed is not malicious
$email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//validation
if(empty($name)){

    header("location: index.html?nouser");
    exit();
}
if(empty($phone)){

    header("location: index.html?nophone");
    exit();
}
if(empty($email)){

    header("location: index.html?noemail");
    exit();
}
if(empty($message)){

    header("location: index.html?nomessage");
    exit();
}




use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';



//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'gamma.cl*********.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'admin@d******.live';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'Br*********';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                 //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Sender
    $mail->setFrom( $email, $name);

    //Recipients
    $mail->addAddress('admin@d********.live','Dj*********');     //Add a recipient

    //Body Content
    $body = "<p><strong>Hello</strong>, you have recieved an enquiry from " . $name . " the message is: " . $message . " you can contact on " . $phone . "</p>";

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Website Enquiry from ' . $name;
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);                   //php function that strips all the html tags out of variable

    $mail->send();
    header("location: index.html?sent");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

I don't know if this will be helpful but below is a screenshot of the debug screen of the php code I ran separately through xampp, without the website code.
[PHPMailer Debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMW4l.jpg)

Any help on what I can do to get the form working will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"When I test the code separately (without the html template) through xampp it works perfectly and sends emails instantly"_ What's different between those two cases then? Does your template have some JavaScript that may be interfering? You tagged your question with jQuery but I don't see any. Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some very basic debugging here. Do you know that your code is even running?